# d3/Javascript animations are not playing when they should be

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation, d3.js

I have the following code to animate an object ("tag") along its path, which is an array of coordinates (x, y, t, where t is the time in between this coordinate and the next one, in ms -- to account for the acceleration/deceleration of the object. The path is generated from a user's mouse movements, and high precision is desirable). The project uses d3.js to animate SVGs.

```
function Animation(tag,path) {
    this.tag = tag;
    this.path = path;
}

Animation.prototype = {
    start : function () {
        console.log('Animation created');
        var i = 0;
        var nextTime = this.path[0].t;
        var thisClass = this;

        setTimeout(function(){}, nextTime );

        console.log('Beginning animation');

        function step() {
            setTimeout( function(){
                if(i == thisClass.path.length -1 ) {
                    var now = new Date();
                    console.log('Animation for '+ thisClass.tag.attr('id') + ' played at ' + (now - globalTimer) + 'ms.');
                    return;
                }
                if(i === 0) {
                    var now = new Date();
                    console.log('Animation for '+ thisClass.tag.attr('id') + ' started at ' + (now - globalTimer) + 'ms.');
                }
                thisClass.tag
                    .attr('cx', thisClass.path[i].x)
                    .attr('cy', thisClass.path[i].y);
                i++;
                requestAnimationFrame(step);
            }, thisClass.path.t);
        }

        requestAnimationFrame(step);

    }
};
```

Another class is responsible for scheduling when each animation is supposed to be played. For example, in a 30-second period, 3 animations have to be played, at times :03, :09, :25. When an animation is needed to be played, the scheduler calls it:

```
new Animation(Tag, Path).start();
```

**The problem:** Although the scheduler calls each animation properly on time, no instance of the function `step()` is executed on time -- they all seem to happen at the very end of the recorded period, all at once. So while one would hope my log to look something like this:

> Animation created
>   Beginning animation
>   Animation played
>   Animation created
>   Beginning animation
>   Animation played
>   ...

... instead, it looks like this:

> Animation created
>   Beginning animation
>   Animation created
>   Beginning animation
>   `(2)` Animation Played

(Edit: http://puu.sh/4Ucw9.png for more details. "Animation pushed" appears on the line immediately after `new Animation(...)`, so in theory, after animation had been completed. As you can see, the three tags (c0, c1, c2) were supposed to be called at different ms marks each, but the animation for all three started at 7019ms)

Animations should play when they are called, not at the end of the time period. It seems like they're queueing up and then all executing at once, but as far as I understand, I didn't tell them to do that. I suspect `requestAnimationFrame` is somehow the key, but I just started using it yesterday, so I'm still not 100% sure what it does and how to use it. Does anyone know what's going on?

Comment: Is there a particular reason for using raw animation frames? You could do all of this with D3's transitions.

Comment: I'm not 100% certain I'll keep using the raw animation frames, but so far, they are the easiest to manage and implement. They are a little messy, yes, but I'd rather get the basics of the prototype working first, and then make the code good, quick, and pretty.

Comment: I'm saying that this would be much easier with transitions.

Comment: "Path" records the user's mouse movements. This means completely arbitrary acceleration, deceleration, direction, etc. Is it possible to faithfully recreate all this using transitions effectively?

Comment: Yes, although I agree that it's probably not ideal for this particular purpose. Anyway, I'm not sure in what way your problem is related to D3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've fixed my issue. Apparently, the problem was with d3 -- because I was using timers but not d3's timer queue, no d3 commands were executed until I got a d3-specific timer to trigger my time-checking function.

In both cases, the function returned "false" until clock reached the next scheduled animation's starting time, at which point the scheduler created the appropriate `Animation()` object and returned "true".

Previous code (didn't animate d3 elements):

`while( !schedule() );`

New code (animates d3 elements on time):

`d3.timer(schedule);`

Strange, I never would have guessed it was d3, but there you have it.